# Select a specific alternative with `fontspec`

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I have recently purchased a font and it has several Stylistic Sets. One of them makes a weird "n" at the end of the word, but also changes the glyphs "{" and "}". As I like the latter, I can't really stand the former alternative, and I would like to be able to only take the alternative glyph for "{" and "}" but not for "n". I cannot post a minimal example, because the font cannot be posted, but I know that the glyphs are number 92 and 94 and the variants are 658 and 659 (according to Apple Fonts). Also, the Stylistic Set that changes them both is `StylisticSet=2` (none of the others change the brackets).

I also attach the screen of the features of the font, in case it might be of any use.

Thank you for any help you can give me.

[image]

Comment: is this text or math? (you could probably use xetex `\XeTeXcharclass` mechanism to substitute { and } by their variants accessed by glyph index, if it is for text.

Comment: or more simply, since `{ }` are accessed by `\{ \}` not directly by characters simply redefine thise commands to get the alternative glyphs, (again assuming text mode, if it's math and you need `\left\{` to grow then  it depends if there are alternate glyphs at all sizes.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. I cannot change the definition of `\{` and `\}` because the font is not used throughout the text but only occasionally. The other mechanics sounds interesting, where can i learn more about it? It is only text style, by the way.

Comment: you can make whatever command switches to that font switch the definition of `\{` (using character classes (see `texdoc xetex`)  you would have teh same issue that you would eed to switch that on and off

Comment: @Logos You could also change the definition of `\{` and `\}` to first check which font is active and insert the right character based on that.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger that sounds an amazing solution. Do you know which `if` statement allows to check the font?

Comment: @Logos If you know the NFSS family name you can use `\str_if_eq_p:nnTF {\f@family} {SomeFamilyName(0)}` (Between `\ExplSyntaxOn`/`\ExplSyntaxOff` of course)